# Stripping a unicode text of whatever is not a character

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to write a simple Python script which takes a text file as an input, deletes every non-literal character, and writes the output in another file.
Normally I would have done two ways:

- use a regular expression combined with `re.sub` to replace every non letter character with empty strings
- examine every char in every line and write it to the output only if it was in `string.lowercase`

But this time the text is The Divine Comedy in Italian (I'm Italian), so there are some Unicode characters like

```
èéï
```

and some others. I wrote `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the first line of the script, but what I got is that Python doesn't signal errors when Unicode chars are written inside the script.

Then I tried to include Unicode chars in my regular expression, writing them as, for example:

```
u'\u00AB'
```

and it seems to work, but Python, when reading input from a file, doesn't rewrite what it read the same way it read it. For example, some characters get converted into square root symbol.

What should I do?

Comment: It looks like Python is treating the file as ISO 8859-15 (8859-1) rather than UTF-8.  You'll have to work out how to set the UTF-8 attribute on the file handle so Python knows it should treat it as such.  I don't know the details; I'm sure it can be done, though.  (Be aware that "èéï" maps to 0xC3 0xA8 = U+00E8,
0xC3 0xA9 = U+00E9,
0xC3 0xAF = U+00EF, but if you treat the byte sequence 0xE8, 0xE9, 0xEF as UTF-8, it is not a valid sequence.  Each of those bytes should be followed by 3 bytes in the range 0x80..0xBF to be valid UTF-8.  In other words, it is not clear your document is Unicode.

Comment: What is a "non-literal character"?

Comment: @Mike Samuel I meant any digit-symbol-punctuation character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`unicodedata.category(unichr)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) will return the category of that code-point.

You can find a description of the categories at [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-4.html#General_Category_Values) but the ones relevant to you are the *L*, *N*, *P*, *Z* and maybe *S* groups:

> ```
> Lu    Uppercase_Letter    an uppercase letter
> Ll    Lowercase_Letter    a lowercase letter
> Lt    Titlecase_Letter    a digraphic character, with first part uppercase
> Lm    Modifier_Letter a modifier letter
> Lo    Other_Letter    other letters, including syllables and ideographs
> ...
> ```

You might also want to normalize your string first so that diacriticals that can attach to letters do so:

> `unicodedata.normalize(form, unistr)`
>
> Return the normal form form for the Unicode string unistr. Valid values for form are ‘NFC’, ‘NFKC’, ‘NFD’, and ‘NFKD’.

Putting all this together:

```
file_bytes = ...   # However you read your input
file_text = file_bytes.decode('UTF-8')
normalized_text = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', file_text)
allowed_categories = set([
    'Ll', 'Lu', 'Lt', 'Lm', 'Lo',  # Letters
    'Nd', 'Nl',                    # Digits
    'Po', 'Ps', 'Pe', 'Pi', 'Pf',  # Punctuation
    'Zs'                           # Breaking spaces
])
filtered_text = ''.join(
    [ch for ch in normalized_text
     if unicodedata.category(ch) in allowed_categories])
filtered_bytes = filtered_text.encode('UTF-8')  # ready to be written to a file
```

Comment: Perfect solution, I quickly examined `unicodedata`before posting but didn't find anything. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('FILENAME', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
    print line
```

1. Will Give you Unicode Formation
2. Will Give you as per written in your file.

Hopefully It will Help you :)

Comment: I still get a: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.